# receiving phishing/spam from known address names and localhost

Tags: spam, email

We are using SmarterMail 11.2 and are receiving spam from senders in our address book (name only, different email).  In the header i see "Received: from localhost" and other suspicious things.  In the past this would be a compromised email account but we have changes passwords and dont believe that is the case here.

NOTE: "[NAME FROM MY ADDRESS BOOK] " the display name is something i recognize, the email address is not

example:

```
Return-Path: <jtw1267@vikingcable.net>
Received: from lead.intertech.net (Lead.intertech.net [24.223.0.82]) by dns19.tntsupport.net with SMTP;
   Mon, 13 May 2013 10:09:39 -0500
Received: from localhost (lead.intertech.net [127.0.0.1])
    by lead.intertech.net (interTECH) with ESMTP id 8668663E92B
    for <MY EMAIL ADDRESS>; Mon, 13 May 2013 09:02:18 -0600 (MDT)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at lead.intertech.net
Received: from lead.intertech.net ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (lead.intertech.net [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id Di0eiZ8JSOQr for <MY EMAIL ADDRESS>;
    Mon, 13 May 2013 09:02:17 -0600 (MDT)
Received: from localhost (unknown [112.208.70.163])
    by lead.intertech.net (interTECH) with ESMTPSA id 835F063E8F6
    for <MY EMAIL ADDRESS>; Mon, 13 May 2013 09:02:14 -0600 (MDT)
From: [NAME FROM MY ADDRESS BOOK] <jtw1267@vikingcable.net>
Reply-To: [NAME FROM MY ADDRESS BOOK] <jtw1267@vikingcable.net>
Subject: Fwd: for [MY FIRST NAME]
To: <MY EMAIL ADDRESS>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 13 May 2013 08:02:46 -0800 (PST)
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Message-Id: <20130513150216.835F063E8F6@lead.intertech.net>
X-SmarterMail-Spam: Commtouch 0 [value: Unknown], SPF_Pass, DK_None, DKIM_None, Custom Rules [], HostKarma - Whitelist
X-CTCH-RefId: str=0001.0A010209.5191025B.003C:SCFSTAT14621567,ss=1,re=-4.000,recu=0.000,reip=0.000,cl=1,cld=1,fgs=0
X-SmarterMail-TotalSpamWeight: 0

hey. what do you think about this? http://www.35lezarts.fr/advertisingbunchbriangordon/


Sent from my iPhone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't necessary believe anything in the `Received:` headers, except the one that corresponds to the mail server that directly spoke to *your* mail server. These are trivial to fake. However, the one added *by your own server* is certainly real enough.

Reading this, I would believe that the valid Received: header corresponding to receipt by your mail server is this one:

```
Received: from lead.intertech.net (Lead.intertech.net [24.223.0.82]) by dns19.tntsupport.net with SMTP;
    Mon, 13 May 2013 10:09:39 -0500
```

Since [the listed abuse contact for 24.223.0.82](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-24-223-0-0-2/pft) is `nobody@example.com` and it seems to be PI address space, I'd suggest just blackholing them, unless you actually know who this company is. In that case, you should call them and find the right person to yell at.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply!  any idea how the email sender display name gets hijacked?

Comment: It's called spear phishing. The criminals get hold of a list of names of company employees from somewhere. It could even be an offline source such as a printed directory lifted from a dumpster. After that it's easy.

Comment: Hmm i do not disagree with you but it seems to be pulling both company and personal contacts

Comment: In that case, maybe somebody at the company got infected with malware that harvested the information.

Comment: I know this is a fairly ambiguous question, but, is there any easy way from a network standpoint to pinpoint this?

Comment: From a network standpoint, not really. You're going to have to pick up the phone... And even then you might not get anywhere.